# Programmatically Add Tag to Wordpress Post Without Overwriting Pre-Existing Tags

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am able to add a tag to my post in code, but it overwrites the existing array of tags. Does anyone know of a way to add a tag to the array of pre-existing tags so that none are erased?

```
wp_set_object_terms($post_id, 'mytagname', 'post_tag');
```

This part of the Wordpress API seems a bit clunky, but maybe I'm completely missing something. Any help would be appreciated!

Turns out RTFM was the answer.

Comment: Just wondering. Why do you want to add tags programmatically.

Comment: @ShaanSingh Because the tag that I am adding is the value of the 'tags__not_in' attribute for a particular query. And upon the admin deciding that they don't want this to show in a particular blogroll, it will disappear/add the tag automatically. This is so that even though some posts may have the same "Category", we can still choose to simply exclude a post or two. Make sense?

Comment: Yup. That makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the fourth parameter of the function - `$append`. If it is set to `true`, the tags are appended to the existing tags, if it's `false` (the default) they replace them.

So you want to call it like so:

```
wp_set_object_terms($post_id, 'mytagname', 'post_tag', true);
```

Comment: Yup, the fourth parameter is very crucial.